# Getting the radius from current location when zoomed in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google map in my android project. I need to get the radius from the current location, when i zoomed in the map .

Comment: Can you post the code you have for the project so we can take a look at it for you?

Comment: I don't have any specific code for that. I just have code for locating the current location on the map

Comment: refer to `com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap` documentation

Comment: Instead of radius like thing you can use Marker or Geofecning to find your area of interest.